# Modify what RSS feed brings into WordPress

Tags: wordpress, rss

(This isn't strictly programming so let me know if there's a better place I could be putting this.)

I'm using an RSS feed to import job listings into a WordPress site. For example, [this feed](http://www.jobs.ac.uk/jobs/law/?format=rss) listed [here](http://www.jobs.ac.uk/feeds/subject-areas) gives me the name of the institution and the salary. However, the site also gives [more information](http://www.jobs.ac.uk/job/AIC243/trainee/) in its own listings. Is there a way of bringing that in as well or is the nature of RSS that you can only take what you're offered?

N.B. I have `Settings -> Reading > For each article in a feed, show` set to `Full text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **your own** feeds you can choose whether to publish your full content or not.

If the site you're referring to chose not to do so, you won't be able to access it. At least not via RSS